# SQL Queries from WCF service avoiding SQL Injection in querying a view

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have my classes from other projects which have strings for SQL queries.

See my example

```
public class OtherClass
{
    myQuery = "SELECT * FROM v_My_View WHERE code = '@code'";
    // I am targeting a view, not a stored procedure
}
```

My question is, if I use this in my `commandText` and just replace the `@code` with a value, is this valid argument against SQL injection?

If it is vulnerable with SQL injection - what are the other options for it?

I tried to use the

```
CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", _obj.code)
```

but it ruined my query.

I am using parameters when accessing my stored procedure, but not when accessing my views.

This is my main:

```
public class Main
{
    public DataTable myMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

            using (SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand())
            {
                CMD.Connection = RBOSUtil.DBConnection();
                CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                // this is the part I used the string from other class
                CMD.CommandText = OtherClas.myQuery.Replace("@code", _obj.code);

                using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD))
                {
                    DA.Fill(myTable);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //close connection
        }

        return myTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, any code which uses string replacement instead of parameters is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use parameters instead of string replacement. I don't know where `_obj.code` comes from, but if it is not sanitised then this is completely open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Are you using `CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", _obj.code) ` or are you using `CMD.CommandText = OtherClas.myQuery.Replace("@code", _obj.code);` or are you using both? It's not clear. If you are using `myQuery.Replace`, thats just string replacement. You aren't using parameters at all

Comment: Once you are using only parameters you are safe from any Sql injection attacks, with only one exception: when these parameters are being used to create dynamic sql. This is not the case here so you should be fine. However, Don't use `AddWithValue`, and don't wrap the parameter with apostrophs.

Comment: It's not clear whther they are using `AddWithValue` or `Replace` to assign the value. I saw the `Replace` before I saw the `AddWithValue` so I assumed the OP is just using string replacement.

Comment: as I said up there. I tried to use parameterized value using CMD.CommandText = OtherClas.myQuery.Replace("@code", _obj.code);  in accessing my view but it gave me an error output. I don't know why but I will still need a time to investigate for it

Comment: I'm using the replacement method for now since I ruined my query in my earlier code using CMD.CommandText = OtherClas.myQuery.Replace("@code", _obj.code); . I want to know if it is not a good Idea. And it seems it is really not :) .

Comment: So to clarify you are using `Replace`, not `AddWithValue` - Hopefully you can see with all these other answers and comments that it wasn't clear to anyone. Anyway, yes `Replace` invites SQL Injection

Comment: I edited my question since it's really a bit confusing :) . And thank you for your answers. I'll try to change it with AddWithValue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
 public class Main
    {
        public DataTable myMethod()
        {
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    CMD.Connection = RBOSUtil.DBConnection();
                    CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //this is the part I used the string from other class
                    CMD.CommandText = OtherClas.myQuery;
                    CMD.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).value = _obj.code;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD))
                    {
                        DA.Fill(myTable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //close connection
            }
            return myTable;
        }
    }
```

declare datatable before try

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I actually tried this but it returned me wrong output. but will this thing really work? maybe I just had a problem with my query if it is really working with a select statement :)

Comment: `CMD.Parameters.Add("@code", varchar(max)).value= _obj.code;` will not compile. You need to use the `SqlDbType` enum to specify the data type of the parameter.

Comment: just define datatable before try block

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes around the parameter name in the SQL statement:
`myQuery = "SELECT * FROM v_My_View WHERE code = @code";`. Otherwise what you're doing looks fine to me. It should work.

EDIT: I got confused between the original question and Ravi's answer. Somehow I missed the separator between the question and the first answer. Anyway, to answer the original question, yes, using String.Replace to replace @code with a value is subject to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

You should use SQL parameters, like the code in Ravi's answer, but you'll also need to modify the query to remove the quotes around the parameter name.

Comment: How can you say that if you don't know if `code` is a string or a number?

Comment: even if code is a string, you don't put quotes around the parameter name. What the original query did `code = '@code'`, was compare the column named code to the static string `@code`, instead of using a parameter named `@code`

Comment: so if my variable is a string, it will work without quote? :) okay thanks for the info

Comment: It's not a parameter. It's a string placeholder that is replaced using `.Replace`. You may as well call it `MyPretendParameter`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The OP shouldn't be using `.Replace` and if not doing that, this answer is fine. The OP already attempted to use a parameter. I do agree some more elaboration helps.

Comment: I got confused between the original question and Ravi's answer. You should use the code in Ravi's answer to use a SQL parameter, and you need to remove the quotes around the parameter name like in my original answer.

Comment: Sorry my original comment was a bit unfriendly - You're right - the question edit has completely changed the answer to the question!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion it cause, I put some statements in a wrong position. And yes I am doing the replacement rather that AddWithValue but to clear it, I tried it also . And will go back to AddWithValue since it really subjectst to SQLi